# Connect to MySQL on GCE using Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, mysql, ssh, google-compute-engine, google-colaboratory

I am trying to access MySQL on GCE VM instance through Google Colaboratory though, unfortunately, it does not work properly but does work in the local VSCode environment.

While executing `TestExec.py`, it shows `SSH Connected` so it seems that ssh connection is successfully done though, however, it seems to be stuck on MySQL connection.

Output on Google Colab:

[image: Output on Google Colab]

**Please help with the solutions/tips?**

```py
    sqlList = []
    sqlList.append("select * from table name;")
    HOST = 'ComputeEngine PublicIP'
    PORT = 22
    USER = 'username'
    DBUSER = 'username for db'
    KEY_FILE = 'private key file path'
    DBNAME = 'dbname'
    DBPORT = 3306
    SSH_BASTION_ADDRESS = HOST
    SSH_PORT = PORT
    SSH_USER = USER
    SSH_PKEY_PATH = KEY_FILE
    MYSQL_HOST = HOST
    MYSQL_PORT = 3306
    MYSQL_USER = DBUSER
    MYSQL_PASS = 'MySQL Login PW'
    MYSQL_DB = DBNAME

    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (SSH_BASTION_ADDRESS, SSH_PORT),
        ssh_pkey=SSH_PKEY_PATH,
        ssh_username=SSH_USER,
        # ssh_password=PASSPHRASE,
        remote_bind_address=('localhost', MYSQL_PORT),
        local_bind_address=('localhost', MYSQL_PORT)
    ) as ssh:
        print("SSH Connected")
        print(ssh.local_bind_port)
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                host='localhost',
                port = ssh.local_bind_port,
                user=MYSQL_USER,
                passwd=MYSQL_PASS,
                db=MYSQL_DB,
                charset='utf8'
            )
            print(connection.is_connected())
            print("DB Connected")

            cur = connection.cursor()
            sql = "use dbname"
            cur.execute(sql)
            # rows = cur.fetchall()
            # for row in rows:
            #     print(row)

            for i in range(len(sqlList)):
                print(sqlList[i])
                sql = str(sqlList[i])
            # sql = 'create table test (id int, content varchar(32))'
                cur.execute(sql)

            rows = cur.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                print(row)
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
            connection.rollback()
            raise err
        finally:
            cur.close()
            connection.commit()
            connection.close()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the connection to MySQL not working, possibly a screenshot or an error message?

Comment: The error doesnt happen. Its stuck on the moment of the picture Ive attached

Answer (score 0):

It seemed the error occurred because of the connection.  I have changed the method of connection.

```py
import pymysql.cursors
connection = pymysql.connect(
  host='localhost', 
  user='user', 
  password='password!', 
  db='dbname', 
  charset='utf8mb4', 
  cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
)
```